# find_element(By.XPATH) not working python selenium

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to select the `input` using the text at the bottom `" hello world "`

```
<p>
"test"
<label for="q906318:1_answer" class="accesshide">
Answer
</label>
<input type="text" name="q906318:1_answer" id="q906318:1_answer" size="11" class="form-control d-inline incorrect" readonly="readonly">
<i class="icon fa fa-remove text-danger fa-fw " title="Incorrect" aria-label="Incorrect">
::before
</i> 
" hello world "
</p>
```

but I can't use the

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'hello world')]")
```

Have you any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
//p[contains(text(),'hello world')]
```

to:

```
//p[text()[contains(.,'hello world')]]
```

or, if the target may be wrapped in another element, test the `p` element's string value:

```
//p[contains(.,'hello world')]
```

If it's the `input` child of the above `p` elements that you actually want, simply append `/input`.

Comment: it seem work thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Please upvote (click the △) if useful and accept (click the ✓) if it solved your problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the p is the only unique element you can use(though it's almost never the case), I would get to this p(with agly xpath or with findElements) and use getText to get the text of this p. Then you'll be able to see the text as Selenium sees it.